# Grid System doesn't shows color as in documentation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I just started to use [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org).
I was trying out [grid](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/grid) elements in my example, I am testing flex attribute. In the example, this shows three different color for each flex element, but in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQdYGY), I am not getting those colors.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
<div layout="row">
  <div flex>
    [flex]
  </div>
  <div flex>
    [flex]
  </div>
  <div flex hide-sm>
    [flex]
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav){
  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
    $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
  };

}]);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css is not included in the example. The colors are there to denote the differences between grid size. You can color them using CSS3 nth child selector. You cand find documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

As an example for your code you can have

```
#parentDivId div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
#parentDivId div:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
#parentDivId div:nth-child(3) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

So an and so forth. Rename `parentDivId` with the ID of parent DIV.

DEMO : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epyQVN

Comment: Ok, I was confused, as these CSS was not included in the angular-documentation. Thanks.